# How to relocate table cell inside a table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a tr and 3 td inside of it. I need to make first and third td width 50% each, and second 100% width and under this two rows. I know that it is strange task, but I need to do exactly this with css or js.[image]

Comment: You need to use an extra `tr`.

Comment: no, I need it exactly in one tr. Or it will be to easy to ask)

Comment: In a semantic way, that is not possible, you rather create another `<tr>` or  use `<span>` with style to do the job

Comment: What im trying to say, you cant change the behavior of `<td>` inside a `<tr>` because the first one must act as columns and not for creating a grids

Comment: You can try 
<tr><td><table><tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr></table></td>

Comment: Ok I understand. The whole point is that table is generated with other script and I can't change the way it generated. Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another, slightly more elegant method, using `flex-box`'s `order` property.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapsed;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
  
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: gray;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  order: 3;
  min-width: calc(100% - 6px);
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>A</td>  
  <td>B</td> 
  <td>C is a really, really, really long content box, showing how the height of a cell doesn't make a difference.</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the most elegant solution so I'll try to think of another method after some yummy dinner. This method uses positioning to simply move the 2nd column to a new row. It requires that your table have fixed-height table cells.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 50%;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 2px);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 1px);
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>A</td>  
  <td>B</td> 
  <td>C is a really, really, really long content box, showing how the height of a cell doesn't make a difference.</td>  
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `td` height are not fixed, It can be changed dynamically by adding content. But I think I can recalculate height if that idea works.

Comment: If that's the case than see the next possible solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/41574495/438581.

Comment: @brett that will actually work with td:nth-child(2) { top: 100%; }

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев - as VilleKoo pointed out a small change can fix the height issue. I've updated the solution to work with variable height cells.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
window.onload=()=>{
//get all trs
var trs=document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(i in trs){
//loop trough
var tr=trs[i];
if(tr.childNodes.length>2){
  //lets split up:
  var nl=document.createElement("tr");
  tr.parentElement.insertBefore(tr,nl);
  nl.appendChild(tr.childNodes[childNodes.length);
 }
 }
 };
```

This changes this:

```
<tr><td/><td/><td></tr>
```

To:

```
 <tr><td/><td/></tr>
 <tr><td>            </tr>
```